# Source of ElementName cannot be found in separate view

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, commandparameter

My WPF application in C# makes use of the MVVM pattern. There are two user controls I have defined:

- LoginView
- ProjectsView

Both user controls are added to a main window and make use of the same view model. The `LoginView` contains a `PasswordBox` defined as follows:

`<PasswordBox Name="passwordBox" IsEnabled={Binding PasswordEnabled} />`

The `ProjectsView` contains a button defined as follows:

`<Button Content="Login" Command="{Binding ProjectLoginCommand}" IsEnabled={Binding ProjectLoginEnabled}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=passwordBox}" />`

When starting the application it seems as if the element name `passwordBox` cannot be bound. The error message is:

`Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=passwordBox' [...]`

How can I fix this?

Comment: why you need a PasswordBox control as your CommandParameter?

Comment: I need the password value (PasswordBox.Password) when clicking the button. However it is not possible to directly bind this due to security reasons. That's why several articles propose to pass the complete control as a command parameter and then access PasswordBox.Password.

Comment: Why don't you try the following code:PasswordBox s = sender as PasswordBox; ViewModel.Password = s.Password; for PasswordBox_PasswordChanged event handler

Comment: I'd just like to avoid event handlers in the code-behind.

Comment: `MVVM` strictly says `View` and `ViewModel` should work in isolation. You should not access View element in your ViewModel.

Comment: Try to use x:Name="passwordBox" instead of Name="passwordBox".

Comment: @RV1987 - where in my suggested code ViewModel knows about View anything?

Answer (score 1):

Your element

```
<PasswordBox Name="passwordBox" IsEnabled={Binding PasswordEnabled} />
```

located in `LoginView` user control, but button

```
<Button Content="Login" Command="{Binding ProjectLoginCommand}" IsEnabled={Binding ProjectLoginEnabled}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=passwordBox}" />
```

located in `ProjectsView`. Problem is that you want to access from one user control child element of another user control. In my opinion it should be better solution to incapsulate all Login UI in `LoginView` user control and your "Projects" UI in `ProjectsView` user control.

Comment: The problem here is that I also need the password from the PasswordBox in elements/commands of `ProjectsView`. Then I would have the same problem vice versa :-)

Comment: If you use same ViewModel for both of your controls you can add in ViewModel some "Password" property, set this property in your LoginView and use it in ProjectsView via Binding.

Comment: Yes, this would work. However this would violate soem security issues, right? I created a PasswordBox property now but it seems more like a dirty workaround though. Actually Microsoft must have some idea of how such a thing should be implemented?

Comment: It seems like MS not cares about any support of MVVM at all, so as for me property of type PasswordBox is good solution for security, and you can use it and don't care about such small violation of MVVM. Also there is another radical workaround: you can create one merged view instead of LoginView and ProjectsView. And then you can pass your PasswordBox as command argument as in your first example.